# Pausing/stopping videos with OnClick event

Tags: javascript, flash, flash-javascript-api

I currently have a onClick event that resets my videos, but this 'reloads' them, is there a way to pause them or stop them without resetting them?

```
<a href="#" onClick='resetVideo("vid1");resetVideo("vid3");return false;'>
```

I currently have this event firing on a navigation button, but it fires every time its clicked (obviously), I really only want to stop a video if its playing - is that possible?

Thanks!

edit (heres my original function):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetVideo(divId) {
if (typeof(divId)=="string") { divId=document.getElementById(divId); }
if (divId.innerHTML) {
org=divId.innerHTML;
divId.innerHTML='';
divId.innerHTML=org;
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're asking about the `resetVideo` function.  Please provide **much** more detail.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for your reply, I just want to know if there are any alternatives to 'resetVideo' like 'pauseVideo'? stopVideo? muteVideo'?

Comment: How are we supposed to know?  You can write any function you want.

Comment: @SLaks - Sorry (newbie alert), not sure how to do that but I've found the original rest function, maybe I could adapt that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your video control.

If it has interfaces that support javascript APIs, then yes.  Otherwise, no.

Without knowing what control that is, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: that makes sense - looks like I've got some homework to do, thanks for the advice!

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could at least point you in the right direction for more info.